# How to select the field that contains numbers and letters?

Tags: mysql, sql

My sql script is like this :

```
SELECT hotel_code, star FROM hotel WHERE star REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$'
```

The result is like this :

http://snag.gy/kQ7t6.jpg

I want the result of select the field that contains numbers and letters.

So, the result is like this :

```
3EST
2EST
```

Any solution to solve my problem

Thank you

Comment: try using `REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9]+$'`

Comment: Try using this REGEXP : `[0-9].[A-Za-z]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're trying to get Must alphanumeric values. It can be achieved by following.

```
^([0-9]+[A-Za-z]+[0-9]*)|([A-Za-z]+[0-9]+[A-Za-z]*)$
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems be like that:

```
'^[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9]+$|^[0-9]+[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]+$'
```

You'll find elements beginning with letters and numbers OR numbers and letters and then containing both ones.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this..

```
SELECT hotel_code, star FROM hotel WHERE star REGEXP '^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])'
```